# Recommended CMS for small .NET websites

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke, orchardcms

I have a site I'm working on creating a cms for in .NET for a client. The site is at http://bit.ly/YJ8dXl

I'm NOT a .NET developer (rails guy here), but I'd like something in c# which I understand well enough to implement on a shared host and create a simple template for.

It was suggested to use DotNetNuke, but that seems much too complicated for my .NET skill set to skin a template for the above site. Can anyone recommend either an open source cms or a proprietary .NET cms that I may purchase a license for cheaply and install on a shared host.

Thanks in advance, I'll plus one any good answers

Answer (score 7):

One more +1 for DotNetNuke.  Umbraco is great (I work with both) but always recommend DotNetNuke for non-heavy programmers. The community is more numerous than Umbraco and it's easier for site admins to learn (it's more wysiwyg).  IF your a die hard programmer needing to integrate custom code - Umbraco might be a better fit.  IF you want to leverage a larger community and *add* code to the base DotNetNuke is a better fit.

The skinning part is easy (alot easier than it looks) and there are plenty of folks around on twitter to help out.

Answer (score 3):

If you like MVC, then Orchard is quite good: http://www.orchardproject.net/

Answer (score 3):

What questions or concerns do you have for DotNetNuke? There are plenty of resources that can get you up and running on DNN, in terms of module development (http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/) and free skin resources and such as (http://multifunction.codeplex.com)

If you aren't a strong .NET developer I personally believe that DotNetNuke is definitely the choice as customizing it is extremely easy even if you don't have to be a .NET developer to use the thousands of extensions available.

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/

Answer (score 2):

Umbraco has worked well for us in the past, we've also put an Umbraco instance onto Azure, seems to be pretty stable.

http://umbraco.com/

Comment: +1 for Umbraco, I moved to it from DotNetNuke and haven't looked back since

Answer (score 2):

I've done a lot of research and attended a few conferences.  My choice was Dot Net Nuke, the reason is quite simple:

- A large developer community.
- Abstraction between Developer, Designer, and Administrator
- Easy to learn and integrate several aspects.
- It won't force a Designer to reinvent the wheel for the site, or the Developer to constantly fix issues the Designer may introduce.

Those are a few of the key elements.

For me it was beneficial for the elements to be abstracted.  I can Develop functionality and modules; while the Designer can create a beautiful User Interface; and an Administrator / Site Moderator can regulate the Site with very little overlap.

Which keeps all our work separated, and people with no desire to learn parts of the platform removed so they always work with what makes them comfortable.

Some of the lessons, and stuff at DNN World also help educate all aspects of people for the platform.

That is my two cents when I did research.

You can Design an entire Dot Net Nuke site without learning `C#` or how to Develop for the Platform. Just like all problems, they need to be taken in small doses; so you can find the proper result.  Chris Hammond who submitted an answer, is actually the Director of Training for Dot Net Nuke.  Also there site has a lot of learning at all levels so you can truly gauge what Dot Net Nuke is.

**Ultimately your asking for opinions, so they may or may not best suite your needs. You may want to be more specific in your question.  Like in Lord of the Rings "Go not to the Elves for counsel, for they will say both no and yes."**

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I can't speak for the other Windows CMS platforms, as I spent over 10 years on non-windows CMS's and e-comm solutions before being sent to a Windows-based team, but having spent the last 6+ years implementing and doing custom solutions using Dotnetnuke, I can tell you that I am impressed by the wide array of (stable) ways you can implement custom functionality within the platform.

There is of course full-blown native module development (in C# or VB), where Chris Hammond's templates and videos can give you a great start,  but there are many other ways to implement custom functionality without going that route if you so choose.

.NET4 and DNN6 introduced razor templates as a way to build quickie, functional customizations where the requirements are somewhat limited in scope. There are also module builder products out there like Open Web Studio (openwebstudio.com) - this is primarily what we implemented with, or XMod Pro (dnndev.com) where you can build more complex modules without doing native coding, and for more front-end heavy stuff you can also look into utilizing 2sexycontent (2sexycontent.org). There are other modules as well like Form & List and complex form builders like dynamic forms (datasprings.com) that may (depending on what functionality you are looking for) provide you with much of what you need. Other modules like Ventrian News can also be used (due to its easy ability to customize with templates) for providing content well beyond news. Having looked at competing (non-windows, they were LAMP stack ones) CMS's, NONE of them had remotely the same options available, and having worked with others who did come from other Windows-based CMS's, they agreed the other Windows ones didn't have as much flexibility either.

I can tell you that after being asked to go back into a non-windows CMS, I looked for options like I mention above to get us able to do rapid development, and they basically didn't exist (JOOMLA for example has Sorcerer and JUMI, and they both are quite poor in comparison).

As for skinning, I usually find a template on the DNN store (store.dotnetnuke.com) that gets me 80%+ of what I'm looking for, and then just modify it myself. dnncreative.com (it's a subscription to see their training videos, but for like $80 you get all 600+ of their videos) has done multi-part series on how to create both regular skins and responsive skins that walk you step by step through all the parts of DNN skins and containers).

Good luck with whatever you choose.

Answer (score 1):

I like using [Actya](http://actya.codeplex.com/) as a lightweight CMS module. It can installed as part of an existing website. Its not currently under active development but the code base is complete enough to make it useful. Plus, its open source so you can modify it to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

One more upvote for Umbraco. They have a hugh developer community and their release cycle is much more consistent which means much quicker release of new features and bug fixes. You can pretty much do anything like a blank canvas and water colors :)

Edit. Umbraco also supports MVC

Comment: `Model View Controllers` are very nifty.  But with Microsoft gearing for a `One ASP.NET` so the limitations hindered within `Web.Forms` or `MVC` should be resolved. If he isn't strong with `C# MVC` may not be the most ideal choice as it can take some time to familiarize yourself with the language.

Answer (score 1):

I have published a CMS on GitHub, CarrotCakeCMS, https://github.com/ninianne98/CarrotCakeCMS that is intended to be a simple framework for folks who want a no-frills ASP.Net CMS but that can easily integrate custom code and can be easily themed/skinned. This is an ASP.Net 3.5 WebForms web application and works in non crippled fashion on shared (medium trust) hosting.

I have a number of additional templates on my project website as well as user documentation and developer guides at http://www.carrotware.com/carrotcake-cms.aspx .  Setup steps are very similar to that of WordPress: unzip files, create site in web server config, create empty database (MSSQL), update config, run website.

Comment: This would be ideal, if it were MVC :) +1 for great effort!

Comment: [MVC5 version](https://github.com/ninianne98/CarrotCakeCMS-MVC) is in progress

Answer (score 1):

Dotnetnuke has been awesome for my career. As far as a rapid development interface, I use XMod Pro by http://dnndev.com

There hasn't been anything I've been "unable" to build.